# How can I make an attendance system that will time in and time out twice a day?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

This is a practicum attendance management system. I'm only using one button to make the attendance work.

```
Dim query2 As String = "UPDATE attendance att, practicum prac SET att.LastName = prac.LastName, att.FirstName = prac.FirstName WHERE att.PracticumID = prac.PracticumID"

Try
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("retry")
    Else
            reloadtxt("SELECT * FROM practicum WHERE PracticumID = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'")
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                reloadtxt("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE PracticumID = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND DATE = '" & logdate _
                & "' AND AM_Status = 'OUT'")
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("you've had enough for this day", "attention", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                Else
                    reloadtxt("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE PracticumID = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND AM_Status = 'IN'")
                    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        Dim amout As String = "UPDATE attendance SET TimeLogOut_AM = '" & timeout_am & "', AM_Status = 'Out' WHERE PracticumID = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
                        Dim QueryString2 As String = String.Concat(amout, ";", query2)
                        updates(QueryString2)
                        load_PracticumAttendance()
                        MessageBox.Show("AM TimeOut")
                    Else
                        Dim amin As String = "INSERT INTO attendance (PracticumID, Date, TimeLogIn_AM, AM_Status) " _
                                      & " VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & logdate & "', '" & timein_am & "', 'IN')"
                        Dim QueryString As String = String.Concat(amin, ";", query2)
                        create(QueryString)
                        load_PracticumAttendance()
                        MessageBox.Show("AM TimeIn")
                    End If
                End If
            Else
            End If
            End If
```

[this is my sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCYUm.png)

Now, how will I make it to have an output on TimeIn - PM and TimeOut - PM? I mean, for example, a practicum will time in by 8am then time out at 12nn. Then they will have a lunch break in which after that, they will time in again by 1pm then out by 5pm. I'm using the PracticumID to input it to the textbox. How do I make it possible to make an attendance afterlunch? because I can only do time in and time out in the morning.

Comment: How much control do you have over database structure?  I would look at redesigning the attendance table with a new field to indicate am/pm then time in/out field’s more generic.  Will also pay you read up sql command parameters to make more robust code

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I'm new to programming. I'm willing to learn.

Comment: Well, to me the table design looks a little off, this is really speculation on my part because I don't know your actual requirements.  Feel you might be better off having a single record for each time in/out combo demarked by Date AND am/pm.  Fields something like PracticumID,  Date, Period, TimeIn, TimeOut.  Where Period is AM or PM.  Else you will have to in effect duplicate everything you've done with AM above for PM with some conditional logic to tell you which to use

Comment: Oohh. I finally understand what you're saying but what I'm trying to do with my program is that a practicum will time in by 8am then time out at 12nn. Then they will have a lunch break in which after that, they will time in again by 1pm then out by 5pm. Do you think it's possible to do that by using only textchange/one button?

Comment: Of course it's possible.  Make it talk to your fancy coffee machine if you want.  But really, this is more sort of a design/requirements thing which is very out of scope for this site.  Being new to programming is probably irrelevant right now, as where you are at is probably the design and logic stage of the project